# Activerecord validation presence on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have following model -

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum commitment: {
           more_than_30hrs_week: 'More than 30hrs/week',
           less_than_30hrs_week: 'Less than 30hrs/week',
           dont_know: 'Dont know'
       }
    enum status: [:open, :closed, :archived]

    validates :commitment, :status :presence => true
end
```

When I try to update project object like the following -

```
@project.update!(project_params)
```

where -

```
 @project = #<Project:0x007fde227059d8
               id: 5,
               commitment: "less than 30hrs/week",
               status: 2 >
 project_params =  {"status"=>"archived"}
```

It throws me following error -

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Commitment can't be blank
```

I fail to understand why is it throwing this error as commitment value already exists and I am not passing in the attributes to update.

Doing the following works but I do not want it this way as I want to update multiple attributes -

```
 @project.update_attribute(:status, 'archived')
```

Can someone please explain, how can I achieve this?

Comment: How about `update_attributes` with the hash as parameter?

Comment: @Iceman `update_attributes` too gives Validation failed error.

Comment: Do you have any callbacks in your model that may remove `commitment` when `status` is changed ?

Comment: @Slava.K No! I don't have any callbacks.

Comment: The real value for key `less_than_30hrs_week` is  "Less than 30hrs/week". Why your `#<Project:0x007fde227059d8
               id: 5,
               commitment: "less than 30hrs/week",
               status: 2 >` is showing the value with lowercase 'L'. 
`'less than 30hrs/week'` is not the value, real value is with capital 'L' `'Less than 30hrs/week'`

Comment: Try removing the `enum commitment` block as a whole, the error must be related to that.

Comment: @Iceman I didn't change any code. It stopped throwing me that error today. I am puzzled :S

Comment: Well, something must have changed, either in your code or code you depend on like a gem or something.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to figure out. As there can't be any magic here. I reverted to yest's commit and checked. Still worked.
Will let you know once I figure out the reason